# Phantomjs wont let me use jQuery ajax POST

Tags: jquery, post, phantomjs

So I'm trying to get the source of a page with phantomjs and then use jquery to post that source to a php page for further processing.

Heres my First PHP page

```
    <?php
$output = shell_exec("sudo /usr/local/bin/phantomjs --proxy=127.0.0.1:8118 --web-security=false ./test.js");
?>
```

And it fires test.js just fine!

I'm running phantomjs on Linux CentOS 64bit

Below is Test.js where I want to go to a git hub page then once its loaded, i want to evaluate the page, get the html for the page, inject jQuery make sure there is no conflicts and then send that page source to post-put-or-get.php.

I've tested jquery and it is being injected and basic dom manipulation is working, I can change the font size of the git hub page etc

I've tried post, put and get, everything on the Test.js page works but not the Jquery Ajax call?

I've tried async on and off, different content types but its like the jQuery.ajax is being ignored for some reason?

Ive even tried ditching jquery and using just javascript to try and post but still nothing, I just cant post?

Am I doing something crazy or is something broke that should be fixed?

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);

};
page.open("https://github.com/logxen/SmoothieBoard/tree/feature/5driver", function(status) {

    if ( status === "success" ) {

    page.evaluate(function() {
    data = document.body.innerHTML;
    console.log(data);


    page.injectJs('jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      async: false ,
      url:'post-put-or-get.php',
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      data:'htmlsource='+data,
      success:function(datafeed) {
        if(datafeed) {
            console.log(datafeed);
        } else { 
            console.log("no joy"); 
        }
      }
   });


    });
    phantom.exit();

    }
});
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?